# StackOverFlow In C# - Lists been created inside lists

Tags: c#, singleton, stack-overflow

Recently I took a online test for a Job application that went really bad.

My Challenge was to create a Rock-Paper-Scissors Game in C# (with a later possibility to add Lizard and Spock).

I Decided to create a abstract class Choice and all the possibles choices gets his behaviour by polymorphism.

And this Choice class has a empty List of Choices with all the possibilities of winning. Like This:

```
public class Scissor : Choice
{
    public Scissor()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        Winners = new List< Choice >();
        Winners.Add(new Paper());
        Winners.Add(new Lizard());
    }        
}
```

The problem is that I'm recreating another instances of Choices (like Paper, and Lizard), with then own List of Winners, and this is creating a Stackoverflow in my program.

My solution for that is: I create the Scissors class I run the Init() method by myself (removing from the constructor). I don't like this approach because looks bad in a "Design Patters" overview. (I can image a other developer creating another class and forgetting to call the Init method.

The Interviewer told that I should use Singleton for that, but I fail to see how that would help.

Can somebody explain for me how this would help ?

Comment: Why do you need a classes here? having a strings or enums will be enough.There is a perfect example of this game in [C# 8 tuple pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#tuple-patterns) sample

Comment: I got your point but the interviewer told me that I should use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good exercise because if you want to do everything in one go (meaning object initialization and winners setup) you'll be standing in a place where you have a circular reference when doing setup.
i.e: Rock: winner -> Paper: winners -> Scissors: winners -> Rock (so in this step you fail into a circle unless you do something to prevent it)

This is my approach using singleton pattern

```
    public abstract class GameChoice
    {
        public List<GameChoice> Winners = new List<GameChoice>();
        public int Compare(GameChoice other)
        {
            // Returns -1, 0, 1 depending on result
            // -1 - Source choice is beaten.
            // 0 - choices match.
            // 1 - Source choice wins.
            return Winners.Contains(other) ? -1 : other.Winners.Contains(this) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    public class Rock : GameChoice
    {
        private static Rock instance = null;
        private static bool WinnersConfigured = false;

        public Rock()
        {
            if(!WinnersConfigured)
            {
                WinnersConfigured = true;
                Winners.Add(Paper.GetInstance());
            }
        }

        public static Rock GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Rock();

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

You can see that the difference with yours is that I have a static instance for each choice type, so you don't create a new instance every time you try to setup the winners for another choice.

And for the circular reference I talked about above, I added a flag to indicate if you already entered the setup for that specific choice. So the second time you try to get an instance for a particular choice, if you're already in setup state, break that reference circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a approach like this, You can make Game class singleton After you have the Game class instantiated, You would call PlayGame method to play with all choices

```
  public class Choice
    {
        public virtual void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Choice Played");
        }
    }

    public  class Rock : Choice
    {
        public override void Play() 
        {
            base.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("Rock Played");
        }
    }

    public class Paper : Choice
    {
        public override void Play()
        {
            base.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("Paper Played");
        }
    }

    public class Scissors : Choice
    {
        public override void Play()
        {
            base.Play();
            Console.WriteLine("Scissors Played");
        }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        //You can make this class singleton
        List<Choice> choices = new List<Choice>();
        public Game()
        {
            choices.Add(new Rock());
            choices.Add(new Paper());
            choices.Add(new Scissors());
        }

        public void PlayGame()
        {
            foreach (var choice in choices)
            {
                choice.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```